# How to Query Facebook uid's for User Friends' Likes

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created an application in Xcode 4.5.  It incorporates a Facebook login process, a query of my friends and their basic info and some newsfeed publishing processes successfully.  However, I am having an issue in trying to query which of my friends have "liked" a certain Facebook object, in this case, a photo. Here is what I have done thus far:

1. Requested the following permissions in the - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI method:user_about_me, read_friendlists, friends_likes, read_stream, 
   friends_likes, user_likes, friends_photos,user_photos.
2. I went on Facebook and found a photo that has been liked by some of my Facebook friends. I then investigated the id of the photo by going to https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.*urlToFBPhoto*
3. I used the following query code (as per the facebook developer page regarding such queries: [url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)) SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="10152365284110475".
4. I was expecting that when I did an NSLog of the resulting data from this query, I would get uids of the few friends who I know like the photo. But instead, the query returned no results whatsoever.

For clarity, here is the full query code I used:

```
- (IBAction)getFriendLikes:(id)sender 

NSString *objectID = @"10152365284110475"; //object id of a friend's FB photo

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:

@"{"
@"'friendlikes':'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=%@'," //no data
//@"'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'," //returns data
//@"'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, sex, pic_big, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN 
//(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)'," //returns data
                   @"}",objectID];


NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            query, @"q", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          }     else {
                               NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }

                          NSArray *friendInfo =  (NSArray *) [[[result 
                                                        objectForKey:@"data"]
                                                               objectAtIndex:1]

                                                objectForKey:@"fql_result_set"];

                          [DataController dc].fbArray = nil;
                          [DataController dc].fbArray = friendInfo;

                          //post callback tasks

                      } ];
           }
```

If anyone can offer any assistance I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you give an ID that gives 0 results for the friendlikes query ?

Comment: 10152365284110475 is an fbID for a photo

Comment: When trying to access that ID using graph api I get a GraphMethodExcetion (100) which means one of `nvalid IDs, non-existent objects, deleted objects, objects which are not visible to the caller due to demographic restrictions, objects not visible because the owner of the content has set privacy settings which exclude the caller, content not visible because the owner of the content has blocked the caller, because the owner of the content has disabled platform apps from accessing any information about their account, etc.` is it possible you just don't have access to see that with your token ?

Comment: hmmm... maybe that is a possibility? Could that be the case if the photo belongs to one of my facebook friends though? I also tried making a post from my app (which works), collecting the postID and passing that in as the object_ID for the above code (after some facebook friends liked the post) and that also returned nothing. Not sure what I am missing...

Comment: Are you using the correct access token ?

Comment: Well, I just looked again at the FB developer page, it says that in order to read the likes table I need:                                                              any valid access_token if it is public (visible to anyone on Facebook) or any valid access_token for the current session user if it is not public and is visible to the user and
read_stream permissions.  I have a valid access token for the user ( I assume since I am able to acquire user friends and other info) and I def have read stream permissions so I am still unable to figure this out.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work after adding friends_photos to my permissions. Thanks for the help!